# vollib issue after pip install

Tags: python, pip

I have installed vollib module as follows:

```
[root@E7440 boris]# python -m pip install vollib
Collecting vollib
  Using cached vollib-0.1.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: lets_be_rational in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from vollib)
Requirement already satisfied: simplejson in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from vollib)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from vollib)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.19.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (from vollib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas->vollib)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas->vollib)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->pandas->vollib)
Installing collected packages: vollib
  Running setup.py install for vollib ... done
Successfully installed vollib-0.1.5
```

Although the installation seems to be a success, vollib module does not function as expected:

```
[root@E7440 boris]# python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Sep 29 2016, 13:33:00) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vollib
>>> c = vollib.black_scholes('c',100,90,.5,.01,.2) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'black_scholes'
>>> dir(vollib)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
>>>
```

For some reason black_scholes and other attributes, such as helper, black and black_scholes_merton are missing or not accessible.

What is wrong?

```
[root@E7440 boris]# python -m pip check
No broken requirements found.
```

No issues are found there...

Where is vollib installed?

```
[root@E7440 boris]# python -m pip show vollib
Name: vollib
Version: 0.1.5
Summary: UNKNOWN
Home-page: http://vollib.org
Author: vollib
Author-email: support@quantycarlo.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: lets-be-rational, simplejson, numpy, pandas
```

Checking vollib location:

```
[root@E7440 boris]# ll /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vollib* -d
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root root 4096 Nov  5 17:16 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vollib
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov  5 17:16 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vollib-0.1.5-py2.7.egg-info
[root@E7440 boris]# tree /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vollib
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vollib
├── black
│   ├── greeks
│   │   ├── analytical.py
│   │   ├── analytical.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── numerical.py
│   │   └── numerical.pyc
│   ├── implied_volatility.py
│   ├── implied_volatility.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── black_scholes
│   ├── greeks
│   │   ├── analytical.py
│   │   ├── analytical.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── numerical.py
│   │   └── numerical.pyc
│   ├── implied_volatility.py
│   ├── implied_volatility.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── black_scholes_merton
│   ├── greeks
│   │   ├── analytical.py
│   │   ├── analytical.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── numerical.py
│   │   └── numerical.pyc
│   ├── implied_volatility.py
│   ├── implied_volatility.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── helper
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── numerical_greeks.py
│   └── numerical_greeks.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── test_black_scholes_greeks.py
    ├── test_black_scholes_greeks.pyc
    ├── test_black_scholes.py
    ├── test_black_scholes.pyc
    ├── test_data.json
    ├── test_utils.py
    └── test_utils.pyc

8 directories, 45 files
```

The module files seem to be presents...

Checking required modules:

```
[root@E7440 boris]# python -m pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=legacy (or define a list_format in your pip.conf) to disable this warning.
apicaro (1.0)
arandr (0.1.9)
astroid (1.3.6)
Babel (1.3)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)
blivet (1.12.8)
cffi (1.4.2)
chardet (2.2.1)
Cheetah (2.4.4)
coverage (4.0.3)
cryptography (1.2.1)
cssselect (0.9.1)
Cython (0.23.4)
decorator (4.0.10)
dnf-langpacks (0.15.1)
docutils (0.12)
enum (0.4.4)
enum34 (1.0.4)
ethtool (0.11)
frescobaldi (2.19.0)
funcsigs (1.0.2)
gresistor (0.0.1)
gwebsockets (0.4)
humanize (0.5.1)
idna (2.0)
iniparse (0.4)
ipaddress (1.0.7)
IPy (0.81)
iwlib (1.2)
Jinja2 (2.8)
kitchen (1.2.1)
laditools (1.0.1)
langtable (0.0.34)
lets-be-rational (1.0.9)
logilab-common (0.63.2)
lxml (3.4.4)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
matplotlib (1.4.3)
meld (3.14.0)
mercurial (3.5.2)
mibian (0.1.3)
mock (2.0.0)
mutagen (1.29)
myhdl (0.8.1)
ndg-httpsclient (0.4.0)
nose (1.3.7)
ntplib (0.3.3)
numpy (1.9.2)
pandas (0.19.0)
pbr (1.10.0)
pdfshuffler (0.6.0)
pexpect (4.0.1)
Phatch (0.2.7)
Pillow (3.0.0)
pip (9.0.0)
ply (3.6)
progress (1.2)
protobuf (2.6.1)
ptyprocess (0.5.1)
pwquality (1.3.0)
pyalsa (1.0.29)
pyasn1 (0.1.8)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.6)
pycparser (2.14)
pycurl (7.19.5.1)
pyflakes (1.0.0)
PyGithub (1.25.2)
Pygments (2.1.3)
pygobject (3.18.2)
pygpgme (0.3)
pyinotify (0.9.6)
pykickstart (2.13)
pyliblo (0.9.1)
pyliblzma (0.5.3)
pylint (1.4.3)
PyOpenGL (3.1.0)
PyOpenGL-accelerate (3.1.0)
pyOpenSSL (0.15.1)
pyparsing (2.1.5)
pyparted (3.10.7)
pyPdf (1.13)
pypoppler (0.12.2)
pyserial (3.1.1)
PySocks (1.5.6)
python-augeas (0.5.0)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
python-dmidecode (3.12.2)
python-ldap (2.4.17)
python-ly (0.9.4)
python-meh (0.43)
python-nss (0.16.0)
python-poppler-qt4 (0.18.1)
python-systemd (231)
pytz (2015.4)
pyudev (0.21.0)
pyusb (1.0.0)
pyxattr (0.5.3)
PyXB (1.2.4)
pyxdg (0.25)
PyYAML (3.11)
reportlab (3.3.0)
requests (2.10.0)
rope (0.10.2)
rpm-python (4.13.0rc1)
scdate (1.10.9)
scipy (0.14.1)
setuptools (18.0.1)
simplejson (3.5.3)
six (1.9.0)
slip (0.6.4)
slip.dbus (0.6.4)
Sphinx (1.2.3)
spyder (2.3.8)
SSSDConfig (1.14.1)
tepache (1.2)
uniconvertor (2.0)
Unidecode (0.4.16)
urlgrabber (3.10.1)
urllib3 (1.15.1)
vollib (0.1.5)
wxPython (3.0.2.0)
wxPython-common (3.0.2.0)
yum-langpacks (0.4.5)
yum-metadata-parser (1.1.4)
```

Everything is there, vollib (0.1.5), lets-be-rational (1.0.9), simplejson (3.5.3), numpy (1.9.2) and pandas (0.19.0) are all present in the list...

I don't understand what is the problem with vollib.
Can someone help me install this package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `black_scholes` is not included in the [`__init__.py` file of `vollib` package](https://github.com/vollib/vollib/blob/master/vollib/__init__.py) so you can't just `import vollib`. Second `black_scholes` is a module which is not callable. The correct usage:

```
import vollib.black_scholes
c = vollib.black_scholes.black_scholes('c',100,90,.5,.01,.2)
```

Comment: Upon installation and import, it says module not found. Even @Philip's solution doesn't work. Any other solution for this?